# How to refer global variable Python?

Tags: python, global, python-2.6

I am trying get the value of 'p1' variable outside a function. I have defined it as a global variable but I cannot reference is outside the function. It gives me error, `"NameError: global name 'p1' is not defined"`

Following is my code. Please let me know how can I get the value of global variable outside my function & also reference it in other function

```
#!/bin/usr/python
import subprocess
import string
def ping_check():
    global p1
    with open ('yst-host.txt') as hl:
            for host in hl:
                    print host
                    p1 = subprocess.call("ping -c2 " + string.strip(host)+ "> /dev/null", shell=True)
                    print "Value of P1 is: ", p1
#ping_check()
print p1
```

Comment: It would help if you called `ping_check` so that the global variable `p1` gets set.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: this is how it works in python. No need to declare anything.

Comment: Just return from the function instead of having global variables! :)

Comment: I'm really curious, why did you comment out the function call that defines the very variable causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code shown, you never actually call `ping_check()`, so your code is more or less equivalent to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print p1
```

And then it's pretty clear that you're trying to use a global variable that doesn't exist yet.

Perhaps you should call your function? And make sure that `hl` is not empty? That way you'll have assigned to `p1` at least once.

---

And for anyone wondering, here's a valid use of `global` in python. Note that we don't need to predefine a global variable, although that might be a good practice (so you can get a known value rather than a `NameError`).

```
def fun():
    global p1
    p1 = 3

fun()
print p1
```

Comment: "Note that we don't need to predeclare a global variable" -variables in python are defined, not declared, and that's probably what's causing so much confusion here. Anyway, +1

Comment: Interesting, I guess in this case `global p1` stores `p1` in `globals()` so obviously it becomes available after `fun()` is called.  The docs aren't particularly clear that `global` can declare a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

This was going to be a comment, but it might actually be the answer.

As sharth points out, you don't need to predeclare a global variable to use it. **However**, it is added to `globals()` (and can be accessed without `NameError` outside the function) after you assign a value to it, not after the `global` statement. This means, that you should check if your code ever reaches the line with assignment.

---

Here's an example:

```
def more_fun():
    global am_i_defined
    print globals() #doesn't include am_i_defined
    am_i_defined = True
    print globals()

more_fun()
print am_i_defined
```

Comment: If I define 'p1' as global outside my function ping_check(), the print globals() doesn't show any value for 'p1' but if I define it inside a function it does show up 'p1' variable's value.

Comment: @Tinku Sorry but I don't quite follow, if `p1` is in `globals()` then your problem is solved...

Comment: Declaring 'global p1' inside ping_check() worked. I had commented the 'ping_check()' function & was never running it, was the issue. Thanks for help guys!